# What is the use of #region and #endregion in c#?

Tags: c#

give me an example what can I achieved if I use this block or not and 
what is the use behind the name after start region

```
#region MyClass definition
//Some code
#endregion
```

Comment: It's for code folding.

Comment: 5 seconds of google: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region

Comment: It creates a named collapsible (foldable) region (it adds the +/- in the gutter, so you can collapse or expand the code enclosed in the region). You could try reading  the documentation.

Comment: it is used for having better formatted, readable  and speculated code

Comment: Thier use is to split large classes into smaller sections for readability. Granted you could argue that if you are using regions then perhaps your classes are too big..but aside from that.. not alot

Comment: Have a look https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell

Comment: As Ken White says, it's used to create different sections inside a class, increasing readability. I recommend you not abuse of it, but it's very handy,

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no (technical) reason to use `#Region`.

The only thing it does is provide an easy way to collapse code.

As an example, for a relatively bulky class; I tend to separate some things in different regions:

- Constructors and properties
- Private or protected methods
- Public methods.

That's just one example. You can separate code however you want, it has no effect on how the application works.

Comment: Partial classes can also be used to separate various aspects of a bulky class.  I use both partial classes and regions regularly.

Comment: @MattDavis: I'm less partial (pun intended) to partial classes than I am to regions, barring for justified use cases such as a partially generated, partially custom built class. I'm aware that both can be used to hide code, but I find that partial classes make it a bit too easy to hide a monolith.

Comment: No arguments here.  I added the comment simply as a reference to others who may find your answer who are interested in managing larger code files.

Comment: Just an update, though this is an old post :-) Using regions inside of a method/function seems to only run the code within that region. For example: if you have two regions inside of a method, and code is run in either one; any code outside (after) the regions will not run. Maybe a new bug? but as this writing in VS 2022 and .NET 6, this occurs.

Comment: @Keltanis: I suspect you are confusing `#region` with `#if`. Very similar syntax, and `#if` does indeed selectively choose which code to run (at compile time). I just confirmed in .NET Core 6, `#region` does not behave this way.

Answer (score 8):

Basically #region-#endregion is used to separate your block of code (it may be your class of function or collection of function whatever you want to specify in.)

Which helps you to identify your block of code with the Key name that explain what you have done inside that region.

It helps you to expand or collapse your code block.
It simplify the way you write your code.
like below

```
    #region "This Is My Function"
    public void MyFunction()
    {
       //Some Code
    }
    #endregion
```

For more details [#region (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region)