# Why is pylance detecting an error in my comment? It was not happening previously

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Here is a snippet of my code:

```py
def fetch_data(boto3):
    try:
        # region = "us-east-1"
        # logger.append_keys(file_used=key)
        # s3 = boto3.client("s3", region)
        # csv_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        # body = csv_obj["Body"]
        # csv_string = body.read().decode("utf-8")
        #df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_string))
        df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user/data.csv")
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Could not pull data from s3. {e}")
```

The error is on line `"# region = "us-east-1""`, the whole thing is underlined in red. When I hover over it, pylance says "#region is missing corresponding #endregion"

EDIT: to add picture.
[image]

Comment: I suggest restarting VS Code, it might just be a glitch. Never happened with me.

Comment: that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Formatting issue? Accidental tabulation?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your error.

Comment: @GuillaumeG indentation isn't a problem when it comes to commenting in any programming language.

Comment: @TheMyth Yes that's true, I meant for the `try:` or `def fetch_data(boto3):`

Comment: @GuillaumeG won't that return indent error?

Comment: @TheMyth After testing with vs2022, yes, my bad.

Comment: #region is a thing in .NET. Not sure why VSCode thinks you're writing .NET code. Did you change the language to c# or something?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi region is used for boto3 package in python.

Comment: @TheMyth screenshot added.

Comment: @w_savage try clicking on view problem.

Comment: VSCode apparently treats `#region ... #endregion` blocks specially. It's not something Python itself knows about, though Pylance (as something developed *for* VS Code) apparently knows about it.

Comment: Basically, you've inadvertently written VSCode-specific "code" without realizing it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44390454/1126841 might be relevant. Apparently, it's intended for code folding, so I suspect that *any* comment beginning with `region`/`endregion` is recognized by VS Code's editor as an editor "instruction", as not all languages supported by VS Code (I would guess) use `#` to start a comment.

Comment: @chepner yes I think you're right. So weird. Wonder why it decided to happen now though.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3308 IMO, the fix is worse than the original problem. I would think PyLance should focus on *Python* problems before editor-specific problems (though I may be overestimating how much PyLance is intended to be used outside of VS Code.)

Answer (score 0):

**# region** will be recognized as a region when it is collapsed.

```
#Region Required.  Specify the start of a region.
string_literal   Required. String (enclosed between double quotes) that acts as the title of a region when it is collapsed. Regions are collapsed by default.
#End Region  Required. Terminates the #Region block.
```

Therefore, it is better to avoid using `# region` when writing comments.

As we do not allow variable names starting with numbers when coding Python.